# Use multiple dbContext on EF Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I am working in an dotnet Core Web API application with **EF Core that use multiple** (two at least) **dbContext** to access tables into two different Sql Server Schemas. For example:

At Sql Server level:

```
Schema 1:
  TableProducts
  TableSkus
  ...

Schema 2:
  TableCustomers
  ...
```

Given the above structure, I am using a repository per table. E.i: ProductsRepository, SkuRepository, CustomersRepository, etc.. Depending on the Schema those tables belongs we are setting the correct schema name at runtime. Until here everything is OK.

However, there is a requirement where on Table (let's say TableCustomer) on Schema 2, needs to access data from other tables on Schema 1.

I was doing some initial search/ investigation on internet on how to achieve this, but no luck so far.

**Basically**, what I want to do is a **SELECT from multiple databases** on the same server. On SQL Server that would be something like:

```
SELECT C.a, C.b, P.c FROM Database1.Schema2.TablePCustomers C
INNER JOIN Database1.Schema1.TableProducts P
ON C.fkId = P.fkId
WHERE C.a == 'some id'
```

But at the **repository level**.

Does anyone have done something similar? Or if you can point out to any documentation that would be OK.

Comment: In the case of multiple databases, you can create a synonym table from the DB server-side. Then mapping it like a normal table in EF.

Comment: What does your repository look like?  If you're using Entity Framework, you're already working with repositories in a unit-of-work context.  Entity Framework already provides that for you, no further effort required.

Comment: If you think about your application with database agnostic. It means ignore different DB schemas. You should think about the boundary context of your domain instead of DB context.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want or need multiple DbContext's. You should define all the tables on a single context. That way you can define the navigations / foreign keys between them.

Comment: Agree with all the other commenters; if you're going to have multiple contexts, the reach of them should be related to the "extent of operations you wish to perform" rather than some artificial boundary like "the sales schema or the hr schema". 

If the orderprocessing context need to pull in sales.orders and the hr.employee that processed the order then those are the tables it should access. If the fulfilment context needs to access sales.product data and supplier.shipping data and hr.employee that packed the order then it should as those represent a "pack order" unit of work

Comment: What is your actual question? Querying multiple databases or querying multiple schemas? Those are two entirely different questions.

Answer (score 0):

> there is a requirement where on Table (let's say TableCustomer) on Schema 2, needs to access data from other tables on Schema 1.

Aand now you know why you shouldn't have lots of different DbContexts.  Just add all the tables to a single DbContext, and if you want to present a more focused view to your business logic you can always layer something in-between the business logic and the DbContext.

EG if you find it convenient to have a ProductsRepository, it would simply wrap an instance of your DbContext and provide access to an `IQueryable<Product>`, and additional convenience methods.